# Grep: Find text in a HEREDOC

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have **9000 PHP files**, most of which contain the text `foo`. I know that the file that I need has the text `foo` in a `HEREDOC`, but it is likely tens of lines away from either the beginning or end of the `HEREDOC` so `grep's -A or -B options` won't help.

Is there any way to perform this search? Is there a better tool to use than grep?

This is on a CentOS 5.2 box, if relevant. Yes, I know that the OS is outdated!

Comment: so all 9000 have HEREDOCs? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: No, not all of the files have HEREDOCs, but a good fraction do! In any case, I see this as a chance to better learn tools like grep and find.

Comment: (fix spelling of previous ver)>  
I understand that you want to find foo only inside of HEREDOC, but to quantify what your task is, try `find . -name '*.php' | xargs grep -l HEREDOCDIVIDER | grep -c foo` will give you a place to start. If you only get a count of 10, then remove the -c and see what you have. Is this a one-time task, are something you need to run every hour until the end of time OR just a learning opportunity. If you don't understand what the code I've included does, execute first part, just before the first pipe, then add in the next segment, to just before the next pipe, etc.

Comment: @shellter: This is a one-time event, but I also want to exploit it as a learning opportunity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty trivial with both `awk` and `sed` but only `awk` has the ability to print both the filename and the line number

```
 awk '/<<<HDOC/{f=1;next}f{if($0 ~ /\<foo\>/)print NR,FILENAME,": "$0}/HDOC;/{f=0}' *.php
```

#### Input

```
$ cat heredoc.php
blah
blah
foo
bar
foo
bash

$str = <<<HDOC
this is a
heredoc which contains
the word foo
more
stuff
here
HDOC;
other lines
with foo
here
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '/<<<HDOC/{f=1;next}f{if($0 ~ /\<foo\>/)print NR,FILENAME,": "$0}/HDOC;/{f=0}' *.php
11 heredoc.php : the word foo
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I need to learn me some awk. This example shows me quite what to learn, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to first recursively search all the `.php` files under DIR that contain a heredoc and then grep only the part inside the heredoc for the word FOO. Doesn't cover all possible cases of heredoc uses in a file, but should narrow the results a bit.

```
egrep -ro --include=\*.php '<<<\w+' DIR | while read a
do
    file=${a%%:*}
    heredoc=${a##*<<<}
    sed -n "/<<<$heredoc/,/^$heredoc;/ p" $file | grep -q FOO && echo $file
done
```

Comment: Thank you, that is clever and there is much that I can learn from it!